# Collection view cell scrollToItem cast fails [Swift]

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

In my swift app I've a collection view with a lot of items, I want to scroll to an item and then set a propriety of the collectionview cell custom class, but the cast fails, why?
Here's my code, I've omitted some obviously steps, but the result is printing of "Cast fails":

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    cv.backgroundColor = .gray
    cv.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Cell.id)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    return cv
}()
```

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell.id, for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.backgroundColor = .purple
    cell.label.text = "\(indexPath)"
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == 14 {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)) as? Cell else {
            print("Cast fails")
            return
        }
        cell.label.text = "Something"
    }
}
```

}

Here's the solution I found:

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func scrollToItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, at position: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast fails as the cell ( of that specific index ) is not visible at the moment you query for it

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)) as? Cell else {
  print("Cast fails")
  return
}
```

instead you can try to set `, at: .top, animated: false)` or wrap the above code snippet inside a Dispatch after block

Btw you should better change the dataSource array and reload that index and that way you don't need a wait

```
// change source array at that index
// scroll to that row with/without animation
// make sure you set value for the cell label in cellForRowAt table's datasource method
```

Comment: Ok, why I can't use performBatchUpdates to get the completion instead of using async thread?

Comment: it's another option try it

Comment: I can't change the source delegate, because I'm creating a chat like whatsapp where when you click over a reply the collection view scoll to the original message and then highlight it.

Comment: ok, I've posted the solution thank you Sn_Khan, 0.5 it's the right time for me